# Adding features to Sequences for Dense or LSTM

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm, feature-engineering

I am confused about the best way to add features to a CNN or LSTM model. Say I have input features where each example is an array of len 10: say [3, 5, 8, 9, 1, 7, 44, 12, 11, 6] and this goes in an array of arrays (X_train), and I pass all through the LSTM or Dense layers and it works just fine.

My issue is that I would like to add an additional feature for each observation, the feature is also an array of length 10, where each position represents "time" for the previous features I described above, so what I want is that for each observation, we have [array of size 10 for some features], [array of size 10 for other features i.e. time].

Should I just extend the time array onto the previous array thereby creating one array of size 20 per example or there is a better way to handle this for training a neural network?

Any points or ideas will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think concatenating the two arrays won't work with either architecture as the time dimension would not be separated from the data point itself, making it difficult for the network to learn from these two different aspects.

Let's say a single training example from your description has a shape `(1, 10)`. If I understood correctly, if you want to add another one of the same size, but representing a single previous time step of the first array, i.e., if you have two arrays of `(1, 10)`, let $x_0$ and $x_1$ respectively, then $x_1(0)$ is a previous time step of $x_0(0)$ and so on. One option is that you can **stack** them and have a two-dimensional example `(1, 10, 2)`. Then, let's say you define a batch of `64`, you will then have a shape of (64, 10, 2), This can be fed to either CNN or LSTM, given that you define the layers with the proper hyperparameters (in CNN the number of channels, and LSTM the number of units).

Hope it helps.